# Related "custom post type" using "custom taxonomy"

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, wp-query

on my "Work" template used for the custom post type with the same name, I have the following code showing a list of titles for every "work". What I want to do is to display 
just on that list the "Works" that have the same Custom taxonomy than the current one.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => asc ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are on a taxonomy or term page then you can simply use:

```
//get current term
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
//get current taxonomy
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'work', 
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'ASC',
    $taxonomyName => $term_slug); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But couldn't make it work, anyway I will show all projects, not just taxonomy related. Thanks!